# 'setup' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use PurchasesConfiguration

Tags: android, ios, flutter, store, revenuecat

How can i fix this and make it not deprecated

```
import 'package:purchases_flutter/purchases_flutter.dart';
class PurchaseApi{
  static const _apiKey = '';
  static Future init() async{
    await Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(true);
    await Purchases.setup(_apiKey);
  }

  static Future<List<Offering>> fetchOffers() async {
   try{
    final offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
    final current = offerings.current;
    return current == null ? [] : [current];
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```

I already changed the firt on to await Purchases.setLogLevel(true as LogLevel); But when i change the setup one i get an error. The error is The method 'PurchasesConfiguration' isn't defined for the type 'Purchases'. I already tried to import'package:purchases_flutter/models/purchases_configuration.dart';

Comment: This is in Flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Deprecated error screenshoot]

When you hover over the deprecated setup method, you have a hint.

You need to replace this:

```
await Purchases.setup(_apiKey);
```

to this:

```
PurchasesConfiguration(_apiKey);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. There has to be an async operation to make sure no Purchase method is called before the setup/configure process is finished and PurchaseConfiguration is an Object, not an async call.

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
await Purchases.setup(_apiKey);
```

With:

```
await Purchases.configure(PurchasesConfiguration(_apiKey));
```